# Two dimensional array size

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
I have problem when I try to initialize this two dimensional array.
 - int A[480][640]
.Error is that the stack is overflow.

Is this error pointing to a compiler or what? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code and error contents

Comment: If you decrease the size of your double array, to say `int A[50][50]`, do you still get the error? You probably are overflowing the stack with that large of a double array.

Comment: No, if I put some smaller numbers I don't get that error. Even with int A[500][500] works fine. But I need the 640x480 resolution.

Answer (score 2):

As others mention, you are overflowing the stack which has a limited size. Large arrays should be dynamically allocated (on the heap) rather than placed on the stack. A vector is a dynamic array. Vector doesn't support 2d directly, but you can simulate it with a vector of vectors. Replace xsize and ysize with your sizes, which don't have to be constants anymore.

```
vector< vector< int > > A(ysize, vector< int >(xsize));

for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
    {
        A[y][x] = x * y;
    }
}
```

Note that y and x index are backwards. It is usually more efficient this way.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are indeed overflowing the stack. There are several ways to fix this, but the easiest two are to either make this `static` or move it outside of your `main` function.

```
static int A[480][640];
```

By making this static, you are basically making it use the data segment of memory as opposed to the stack (and overflowing it in this case because of the large allocation). In the image below, it would be in the 'initialized data', which is also where global variables are stored (the reason why the second option also works), outside of the stack/heap.

[image]

or

```
int A[480][640];
int main(int, char **) {
    //....
}
```

Comment: Yes, great, with adding this static in front I've solved the problem. Ok, I will do like this - but first must see what does that "static" means in this kind of use :)

Comment: I added some more info to my answer, as a small explanation of why making this `static` works.

Comment: Making the array dynamic is a better and more general solution. Making it static or global is just a quickfix.

Comment: True, but if you do not need to access this variable outside of the given function/class then it is not necessarily a 'bad' fix.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?
2D array is initialized like this: (C#)
`int[,] A = new int[x,y];`

Comment: I'm using C++ where you initialize like this: int A[x][y]